# Ошибка при многоразовом нажатии на кнопку Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Подскажите как отключать кнопку или не производить никаких действий пока страница не перезагрузится . Проблема в том что если быстро нажимать на кнопку посылаются запросы в бд и получаю ошибку ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

```
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51011)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Новая папка\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Новая папка\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
```

Проверил на других приложениях ошибка та же самая,  при многочисленном клике на любую ссылку, главная проблема в том что если идет запрос в бд он идет много раз , при регистрации если кликнуть 2 раза скажет что такой пользователь уже есть и не успеет перенаправить на следующую страницу

Comment: сделать ее неактивной, наверное, пока не дождешься ответа от сервера?

Comment: возможно , можно ли это сделать как-то без js?  возможно через middleware ?